# Blender Game Engine: Texture Resolution Setting?

Tags: textures, blender

Is it possible to change the texture size while running the Blender Game? For example for computers with less RAM. Thank you!

Comment: There is no built-in way. I would expect the need to have a script go through textures and adjust the image used for each. Maybe a set of textures could be made available in "tex_2k" and "tex_1k" folders with materials reading from "tex" which is a link created at run time to the set you want to use.

Comment: How does this work in other Games? Do they also have different folders for high, Medium, low or do they live resize it while loading (But wouldn't that take a lot of performance?)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial which explains LOD (Level of Detail), which is what you are trying to achieve.
https://www.blendernation.com/2015/09/13/9-ways-to-optimize-a-game-in-bge/

about your question in the comments,
other games have different methods for doing the dynamic texture resolution, the most advanced being not using textures at all, only materials, but some do have separate files for the different resolution textures, although LOD files are not usually separate files in a folder but a special package file. Some do it dynamically by just having one big texture and then scaling it down with algorithms.

however, it is notable that most often texture sizes aren't so important to optimize as poly-counts.

Comment: But I want to load that textures in a lower resolution for lower ram usage etc. No LOD

Comment: You are talking about mipmaps, this specific feature is enabled by default in the blender game engine or blender in general, essentially you wont notice unless you have very low ram or play around with the distances and other settings. You only need to produce the biggest texture file, and blender will generate the smaller versions on its own at runtime. This is the last method I was talking about in my answer. You should watch that video as it includes a section for texture optimization. Also, play/test your game in its .exe compiled form to see the mipmapping more easily.

Comment: But it loads the full resolution texture into the ram. I want that it loads the downsized texture. Imagine one computer with low RAM.

Comment: Have you tried running your game on an actual computer with low ram? otherwise, go here https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?189973-Changing-object-textures-in-game-engine-quot-on-the-fly-quot-(animated-textures), you would need to write code to change each texture yourself, probably just once from a menu